# What library does the Beetle BLE utilize for BLE commands?

Tags: library, ble, bluno

I am trying to pair two gloves containing beetle BLE's on each, one set to a peripheral role and one to central to control leds for kids' party jewelry.

The Arduino.BLE library does not work with this board.  Is there another BLE library that is compatible with the Beetle BLEs, that will allow me to use the NOTIFY command?

Comment: AT commands https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Bluno_SKU_DFR0267#Configure_the_BLE_through_AT_command